# C fibonacci and equation problem with my code

Tags: c

Hello im new to C programming and this is my C Quiz question.
I tried really hard but i cant find the solution or whats wrong with my code.
This equation block cant work.
Any help will be appreciated

Write a C program that displays the below menu and performs the
corresponding operation, according to the selected menu item.
Write separate functions for each menu item and call the related function according to the
selection.
The menu:
(1) Calculate fibonacci value of the entered number,
(2) Calculate the equation (Get value of R from the user),
(3) Get four numbers from the user, sort them in ascending order
Enter your choice:

When the user enters a number (1, 2 or 3) corresponding function will be called
to perform the operation.
The user will enter -1 if he wants to continue and the
menu will be appeared on the screen again.

[Question Equation Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzu1l.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fibonacci(int numForFibonacci)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int k = 1;

    for (int b = 1; b <= numForFibonacci; b++)
    {
        k = i + j;
        printf("%d \n", i);
        i = j;
        j = k;
        printf("%d ", k);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return k;
}

float theEquation(float numR)
{
    float multipl, result = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numR; i++)
    {
        multipl = (2i + 4) / (i * i);
        result *= multipl;
    }
    printf("Result is %f", result);
    return result;
}

int ascending(int n)
{

    int k = 0, i = 0, j = 0, number[4];
    for (int w = 0; w < n; w++)
        scanf("%d", &number[w]);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (number[i] > number[j])
            {
                k = number[i];
                number[i] = number[j];
                number[j] = k;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("\n%d \n", number[i]);
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int choice, choiceFibo;
    float choiceR;
    do
    {
        printf("[1]Fibonacci calculation\n");
        printf("[2]calculating the equation: (2k+4)/(k*k)\n");
        printf("[3]sorting numbers in ascending order\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            printf("enter a number for fibonacci\n ");
            scanf("%d", &choiceFibo);
            fibonacci(choiceFibo);
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            printf("[2]enter a number for (2k+4)/(k*k)\n");
            scanf("%f", &choiceR);
            theEquation(choiceR);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("[3]enter four numbers to sort them in ascending order\n");
            ascending(4);
        }
        printf("If you want to do another calculation enter '-1'.\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while (choice == -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: `multipl = (2i + 4) / (i * i);` C has a math touch, but this is too much: `2 * i`. like `i * i`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Two main issues:

- `<integer>i` in GNU C represents a complex number, not multiplication.
- integer division is not what you'd expect

Your issue lies on this line:

```c
multipl = (2i + 4) / (i * i);
```

You might think that `2i` would evaulate as `2 * i`, but in C, `2i` is a complex int.

This can be seen here:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    printf("%d", 2i);

    return 0;
}
```

You would expect this to print `2`, but instead we get a warning.

Compiled with onlinegdb:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘complex int’
```

Second issue: Integer division. The other answer already covered it pretty well, but for the sake of self-contained answers:

In C, integer division finds the integer solution and discards the remainder.

```
2/5 = 0 
6/5 = 1
10/5 = 2
10/4 = 2
10.0 / 4 = 2.5
(double)10/4 = 2.5
```

You need to "type coerce" one of the values in your numerator or denominator to a float/double, which will coerce the entire fraction to a float/double.

You can do this either with `2.0*i` or `(double)2*i`. Either one works, but the second one is more explicit for readability.

To fix the issue, simply change `2i` to `(double)2*i`.

Comment: Re “`<integer>i` in C represents a complex number, not multiplication”: That is a GNU extension, not standard C.

Comment: If you want more details on exactly how the type of an expression is determined when it contains variables of different types,  "type promotion" and "type conversion" are the keywords to search for.

Answer (score 0):

There are only three edits required to get a *clean* compile:

- Change `int main()` to `int main(void)`
- Change `(2i + 4) / (i * i)` to `(2*i + 4) / (i * i)`
- Change `int ... number[4];` to `int ... number[4]={0};`

If you did not see something similar to the following upon your compile, then turn on all warnings:

```
>  s0_15.c - 4 warnings   
>       28, 28    warning: implicit conversion discards imaginary component: '_Complex int' to 'float'    
>       45, 17    warning: variable 'number[i]' may be uninitialized when used here 
>       38, 5     note: variable 'number' is declared here   
>       54, 27    warning: variable 'number[i]' may be uninitialized when used here 
>       38, 5     note: variable 'number' is declared here   
>       58, 5     warning: function declaration isn't a prototype.
```

To ensure accurate calculations, see integer division addressed in another answer under your post.